# Using [Bind(Exclude='ID')] in DNX 5 with no System.Web

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dnx50

I've read that you can use:

```
[Bind(Exclude="id")]
```

to stop an ID field from invalidating a ModelState when creating a record from a 'Create' action.

With DNX Core 5 *System.Web* is no longer available. Is there an equivalent way to ignore an auto-generated ID or am I in the same boat as this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34847744/2591770

**UPDATE**
It seems as though items can be removed from the ModelState directly as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169910/2591770

I'm still interested in any other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a view model and then map the posted values to an instance of your entity. That way, only the properties you place on the view model may be modified. `Bind` is an anti-pattern anyways.

Comment: I wish `[Bind]` and `[Include]` never existed in the first place, as they introduce really bad habits concerning model binding. Using a viewmodel is ideal for the OP's situation, so a big +1 from me.